# Why are the extensions of valuations in a Galois extension conjugate under the action of the Galois group?

Tags: galois-theory, ramification

I'm reading the following paper by Hansen about Galois Coverings of Curves: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.9776&rep=rep1&type=pdf (see page 37)
Unfortunately, I'm having problems with the following argument:

Let $K/L$ be a finite Galois extension and let $\nu$ be a valuation of $L$.
$G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/L)$ acts on the valuations $\nu^\prime$ of K by $\sigma(\nu^\prime)=\nu^\prime\circ \sigma$ for all $\sigma\in G$.
We see that $\sigma(\nu^\prime)|_L=\nu^\prime\circ\sigma_L=\nu^\prime|_L=\nu$ for a valuation $v^\prime$ of $K$ with $\nu^\prime|_L=\nu$

Hansen argues that, since $G$ consists of all automorphisms of $K$ fixing $L$, the valuations $\{\nu^\prime\text{ of }K: \nu^\prime|_L=\nu\}$ are conjugate under $G$'s action.
I don't understand why this follows from the above. I would be very thankful if you could give me a hint.

Comment: I agree it is not obvious why the set of all $v'$ restricting to a common $v$ on $L$ are in the same $G$-orbit just from the fact you say Hansen states.  Do you know a proof in algebraic number theory that in a Galois extension $E/F$ of number fields, all prime ideals in $\mathcal O_E$ that lie over a common prime ideal of $\mathcal O_F$ are in the same Galois orbit?

Comment: Anything unclear ?

Comment: @KCd I'm in a number theory course this semester but up until now we have not covered  this proof. Maybe I can find it in Neukirch or other Literature. 
How does that prove that the valutations are conjugate?

Comment: The proof would be analogous, since (nonzero) prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ in the ring of integers of a number field $F$ describe all non-Archimedean valuations on $F$: they are ${\rm ord}_{\mathfrak p}$, up to scaling factors. In the notation you use, valuations on $K$ extending a given valuation on $L$ are like prime ideals in $\mathcal O_F$ lying over a given prime. When $F/\mathbf Q$ is Galois, transitivity of the Galois action on the prime ideals over a given prime number can be proved with the Chinese remainder theorem and the answer by reuns uses CRT-type ideas in its "main claim".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $K/L$ a (finite) Galois extension of any kind of fields, $w$ a valuation on $L$ and $v_j$ (the equivalence classes) of valuations on $K$ extending $w$ . There are finitely many such valuations.

$G=Gal(K/L)$ permutes the $v_j$ as $v_j \circ \sigma$ is another valuation above $w$.

> The main claim is that there is $\pi_1\in K$ such that $v_1(\pi_1)>0,v_j(\pi_1)=0$.

Since $K/L$ is Galois then $N_{K/L}(\pi_1)=\prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(\pi_1)\in L$.

$$w(N_{K/L}(\pi_1))=v_1(N_{K/L}(\pi_1))=\sum_{\sigma\in G}v_1 \circ \sigma(\pi_1)\ge v_1(\pi_1) > 0$$

Whence for all $j$, $v_j(N_{K/L}(\pi_1))> 0$ so that $v_j \circ \sigma(\pi_1)>0$ for some $\sigma$ which implies that $v_1 = v_j\circ \sigma$.

---

If $w$ is a discrete valuation then once we know that there are finitely $v_j$ the main claim follows easily. The $v_j$ are discrete valuations because $[L:K]$ is finite. Look  at $S_1 = \{ a\in L, v_1(a)=0,\forall j, v_j(a)\ge 0\}$. For each $j$, if it exists take some $a_{j,1}\in S_1,v_j(a_{j,1})>0$ and let $A_1 = \prod_j a_{j,1}$. If some $a_{i,1}$ doesn't exist then take some element $b\in L,v_1(b)>v_i(b)$. Letting $c=bA_1^n$, for $n$ large enough then the minimum valuation of $c$ is at some $v_m$ such that $a_{m,1}$ doesn't exist. Taking $k\in K,w(k)\ne 0$ then for some $r> 0,s$, $r v_m(c) =s v_m(k)$,
$d=c^rk^{-s} \in S_m$ and $a_{m,1} = 1-d$ exists. Thus in fact all the $a_{m,1}$ exist and $\pi_1=1-A_1$ works in the main claim.

Comment: That's great! Thank you for your help! Is there a trivial proof of the main claim that I just don't see or is it a result of some theorem?

Comment: See my edit ${}{}{}$